# How to retrieve a post by inputing the url in a custom field and displaying it on an options page

Tags: posts, custom-field, urls

If have an options page where I have a custom text field and I want to paste a url of a post
in that custom field and retrieve the Post Title and Excerpt and display theme above the custom field and then be able to repeat that and put it in a list above the field how wood I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use url_to_postid function to retrieve the post id from a URL.

Comment: You cannot use the full URL according to the codex. What I want to do is to allow my contributors to is past a url of their post on the front end into an options page build a list then email that list to a receiver of that email